# Parsing a file to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, file, nsdictionary

How can I parse a txt file to a NSDictionary?

my file looks like

```
JACK - (mr) - address
99000 - City
Phone : 09 93 81 48 51
Website
```

this is my code:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error;

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSArray * testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
testArray = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" \n"];
```

and after

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *s in testArray)
{
    NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@" -"];
    [dict setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]);   
}
```

and my NSLog gives me:

```
Dictionary: {
        name = "JACK";
}
```

how to parse the rest of the file to get "mr" and after the address ....?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, it appears that you are only asking arr for the first element in the arr array. Try this:

```
int i= 0;
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *s in testArray)
{
    NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@" -"];
    for(NSString * pstrSubComponent in arr)
    {
          [dict setObject:pstrSubComponent forKey:paKeysArray[i++]];   
    }
}

NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]);
```

You'll have to make the paKeysArray with all the keys you expect to use in your file. This assumes you know the order of the data in the file and that it's consistent.